# Add Entity Framework 7 to an MVC 5 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm creating a new MVC 5 website, I'm fine using Entity Framework 6.1 for my SQL Server Database. The project is going to be hosted in Azure, and some of the data is going to Table Storage. I've seen that in Entity Framework 7 I can create a DbContext using Azure Table Storage and I'd like to do use it. I have Visual Studio 2015 preview, and I've managed to install EF7 on ASPNET 5 MVC 6 apps. But I can't get it to work with MVC 5, any ideas how I could achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: An MVC6 application will not work with MVC5 , at least I don't think it will.  It's like using visual studios 2012 and trying to open an MVC5 application , it won't work.  Microsoft just announced last week that they are moving towards Visual Studios Community,  instead of 2015.  For production applications stick with what is already out and stable,  to play around and look at new features , then use 2015

Comment: Can you provide details on what exactly "doesn't work".  Error messages, etc?  Were you able to install EF7 into your MVC5 application?

Comment: I haven't been able to install EF7 in my MVC 5 project, I added the myget sources feed to get EF-beta, but I get that the dependency 'lx-async' can't be resolved. If I create a library project and try to install EF7 I get the same problem. Do I need ASPNET 5 to use EF7? Scott, I'm not trying to use MVC 6 in an MVC 5 project, I'm trying to install EF 7.

Comment: See https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/657

Comment: I agree with Scott Selby. Unless this is a personal learning project stick with the stable release.

Comment: @ChristopherWhite re-read the question.  The question is about installing EF7 into an MVC5 application.  It doesn't have anything to do with MVC6, and I don't know where this notion of VS2015 being dropped in favor of the community edition is coming from.

Comment: I read the question just fine. I didn't make any assertions about any of what you brought up. I simply made a statement that if he is expecting to publish this to a live site then he should stick to stable released code ie. not use EF7, ASP.NET 5 or MVC6. I stand by my comment.

Comment: MVC5 isn't tied to EF. I think your problem is with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF7 is built on the K-runtime Environment (like MVC6 i.e VS2015 only at the mo), so it's just incompatible with MVC5, no way round that.

disclaimer: the rest is my opinion

I've tried the EF7 Azure Table Storage (ATS) extensions in an MVC6 project and not only was the performance not on par by quite a margin (might have fixed that by now), but a ton of features that you're used to in EF aren't available, because they can't be.  EF is great for relational databases, I love it, but trying to treat ATS anything like a relational database will only get you in trouble.

It abstracts important knowledge away from the developer that you need if your going to develop performant and scaleable systems.

ATS can only guarantee transactions to a single partition at a time, not across partitions, i'm not sure how EF (where you can modify entities in multiple partitions) can deal with this.

EF7 doesn't let you span contexts across multiple storage accounts, which is a massive problem if you start to reach Partition/Entity limits (20,000/sec per account, 2000/sec per partition).

EF7 doesn't allow for multiple entity types in a single table, or the ability to resolve to different DTOs, you have to do that mapping in memory instead.

Shortly after testing it I went back to just using the azure storage clients instead and I don't think i'll try it again. The storage clients were designed specifically to work with ATS in the manner in which it was developed.  Although i'm still looking forward to using EF7 with SQL when it's ready.

Comment: but, you can see here ( http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2015/07/20/entity-framework-and-visual-studio-2015-rtm.aspx ) that ef7 targets .NET 4.5.1 or later

Comment: At the time of writing (over a year ago) this wasn't the case